# convert the monolithic kernel of linux into microkernel

Tags: kernel

i want to convert the **old monolithic kernel** of Linux into **microkernel** (not the latest one but it may be older once like **1.0** or something) plz tell me is this possible or not(if not tell me the challenges that we have to face  ) . tell us and if possible give us the useful link about some video tutorial from where i get the way of making this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. And "possible" is all it is. This would require you modifying the source code of the core of Linux. There's no way to do it on an already-built system. It would require an enormous amount of work to "port", or in-place convert, something as complex and widely-depended on as the Linux kernel to a totally different architectural pattern. We're talking thousands of hours of work and millions of lines of code. Even if that were successful, it probably wouldn't work with almost every available Linux driver, module, or kernel-hook-dependent library (i.e. libc).

However, if you want to see what GNU/unixish system that runs on a microkernel looks like, take a look at [GNU/hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html). It's a robust enough microkernel system that you can run Arch Linux--er, [Arch Hurd](http://www.archhurd.org/)--on it.

This topic has been discussed before. To review some of the discussions about why/how likely it is that Linux itself (rather than an alternative like hurd) would ever switch to a microkernel, browse [this thread](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/00/07/30/075212/could-linux-become-a-microkernel).